# Проблема с отображением скриптов JS в компоненте WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

есть html-документ, в котором присутствует использование скрипта при помощи: 
`<script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>`

Но, когда я загружаю данный html-документ в WebBrowser, то получаю "Ошибка сценария" и сам скрипт перестает работать.
Загружаю данный html-документ с помощью: `webBrowser1.DocumentText = Properties.Resources.HTMLDocument;`

Как можно исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Для каких целей вам нужен браузер? Чисто отображение контента или чего то больше? Если чисто контент, то стандартный WebBrowser уже давно устарел, лучше взять наверно что то более современно, стороннее (CefSharp например). Если идёт работа с самой страницей, то пробуйте работать с запросами, а не с html, ну или используйте например Selenium.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а если именно требуется WebBrowser? Или вариантов решения для него не существует?)

Comment: Не думаю. WebBrowser - это IE, по умолчанию он вроде IE7. Можете попробовать сделать что то вроде [этого](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version). Но не факт, не факт...